# Create a query on unstructured XML data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a column that holds xml data in SQL Server. I have 2 values in my column, the data looks like this:

```
<StoreSurvey>
    <BankName>United Security</BankName>
    <BusinessType>BM</BusinessType>
</StoreSurvey>
```

and this :

```
<StoreSurvey>
    <AnnualSales>2000</AnnualSales>
    <BankName>United Security</BankName>
    <BusinessType>BM</BusinessType>
</StoreSurvey>
```

As you can see these two values has a different on `AnnualSales`. How can I write a query to return the records with `AnnualSales=2000`?

Sorry I am so new in XML data type.

Answer (score 0):

As your is question is  not clear whether you are asking to join both the result sets or filter the record where Annual sales = 2000

here is the example basing on assumed data

```
Declare @XmlStr XML;
SET @XmlStr='<StoreSurvey>
  <AnnualSales>2000</AnnualSales>
  <BankName>United Security</BankName>
  <BusinessType>BM</BusinessType>
</StoreSurvey>

<StoreSurvey>
  <BankName>United Security</BankName>
  <BusinessType>BM</BusinessType>
</StoreSurvey>';
```

Script where you can only get Annual sales = 2000

```
SELECT
    [Table].[Column].value('AnnualSales[1]', 'int') as 'AnnualSales ',
    [Table].[Column].value('BankName[1]', 'varchar(20)') as 'BankName',
    [Table].[Column].value('BusinessType[1]', 'varchar(50)') as 'BusinessType'
FROM 
    @XmlStr.nodes('/StoreSurvey') as [Table]([Column])
WHERE 
    [Table].[Column].value('(AnnualSales[1])[1]', 'int') = 2000
```